# tcolorbox with quotes

Tags: citing, tcolorbox

I would like to make a newtcolobox with quotes like this one for example (with a bit more older styles quotes) :
[image]

Does someone know how I can do it ? (I mean to have the quotation marks on the border of the tcolorbox)

Prehaps it must be done with tikz but I'm not used to it...

I tried to make an overlay, but I don't know how to insert text in a scope environment (thus quotes).
This is what I mean (but it doesn't work at all):

```
overlay={%
     \node [block]   
([xshift=3mm,yshift=-0.02cm]frame.north west){“}
```

My basis for the tcolorbox is this :

```
    \newtcolorbox{citation}[1][]
{
colback=themecolor!10,
coltitle=black,
colbacktitle=themecolor!30,
arc=0pt,
boxrule=0pt,
title=\textsc{#1}
}
```

Comment: Not `tcolorbox`, but a similar output: [Block quote with big quotation marks](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/16964)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually draw the quotes using `tikz`. You need `skin` library and `enhanced` option, in order to access the `geometry nodes`. See [manual](https://ca.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) page 82. Command `\leftsp` defined to set the location of quotes from left side of the box. I set the optional arg #1 on the general option for the tcolorbox (not for `title` key). I think this should be the way the option be defined. Because you could always say: `\begin{mycitation}[title=citation title]`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\definecolor{themecolor}{named}{red}
\newcommand{\leftsp}{0.3cm}
\newtcolorbox{mycitation}[1][]
{
enhanced,
colback=themecolor!10,
coltitle=black,
colbacktitle=themecolor!3,
arc=0pt,
frame empty,
overlay={%
\begin{scope}[shift={(interior.north west)}]
\filldraw [themecolor!60] (\leftsp,0.1cm) -- ++(-0.075cm,-0.15cm) -- ++(0,-0.06cm) -- ++(0.08cm,0) -- ++(0,0.06cm) -- ++(0.055cm,0.155cm) --cycle;
\filldraw [themecolor!60] ($(\leftsp,0.1cm)+(0.2cm,0)$) -- ++(-0.075cm,-0.15cm) -- ++(0,-0.06cm) -- ++(0.08cm,0) -- ++(0,0.06cm) -- ++(0.055cm,0.155cm) --cycle;
\end{scope}
},
#1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mycitation}
this is a citation
\end{mycitation}
\begin{mycitation}[title=citation title]
this is a citation
\end{mycitation}
\end{document}
```

[image]